# Как декларировать динамические свойства объектов в TypeScript

Tags: vue.js, typescript

Приме из компонента **VueJs**(Версия: **2**, **`class-style-component`**):

```
    <v-container>
      <v-row
        v-for="(item, index) in shortcodes"
        :key="index"
      >
        <v-col>
          Замена №{{ index }}([__{{ index }}__])
          <edit-select-dropdown-options-single
            :ref="`editSelectDropdownOptionsSingle${index}`"
            :value="item.options"
            @select-option="setAnswer(index, $event)"
            @remove-option="removeOption(item.options, $event)"
          />
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
```

Формируется динамический `ref`. Далее мне необходимо обратится к этому `ref`:

```
this
 .$refs[`editSelectDropdownOptionsSingle${replacement.shortcode_key}`}[0]
  .someMethod(someArgs);
```

Документация по [`refs`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref).

Как мне описать что по этому ключу есть массив с и у каждого элемента доступен метод `someMethod`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добился желаемого результата без глушилок(`eslint-disable-next-line`,`@ts-ignore`).

```
const name = `editSelectDropdownOptionsSingle${replacement.shortcode_key}`;

const refs = this.$refs[name];

if (Array.isArray(refs)) {
  const component = refs[0];

  if (component instanceof EditSelectDropdownOptionsSingle) {
    component.setSelected(shortcodes[replacement.shortcode_key].options[0].id);
  }
}
```

Возможно, я что-то не понимаю, но почему-то **TSC** не понимает без этих проверок, что `$refs` может содержать массив и я могу обратится к этому массиву по нулевому индексу и элементом будет экземпляр класса `EditSelectDropdownOptionsSingle`, который унаследован от `Vue` и является компонентом.

Answer (score 0):

Ну если по-деревенски, то как-то вот так.

```
interface MySpecialComponent {
 someMethod: (payload: string) => void
}
```

и в коде:

```
(this.$refs[`editSelectDropdownOptionsSingle${replacement.shortcode_key}`] as MySpecialComponent).someMethod('Два прихлопа три притопа');
```